# Using case in a aggregate sql query without splitting rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In ms-sql i am using an aggregate group to filter results by user, i would also like to use case to filter by a row not contained in the aggregate so all the user results are on 1 line. I'm not sure this is possible.

Here is the query below which splits the results into two lines.

```
select case  when col_A='1' then sum(col b) End as Sum1_results,
case  when col_A='2' then sum(col_b) End as Sum2_Results, Username from tbl1
group by Username, col_A
```

example of results is.

```
Sum1_results | Sum2_results | Username 

 5499          null           John
 null          3400           John
```

Ideally, i would like to just have these results merged into one line for each username if possible. 
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
select Username ,
     SUM(case when col_A='1' then col_b End) as Sum1_results,
     SUM(case when col_A='2' then col_b End) as Sum2_Results, 
from tbl1
group by Username
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and editing the question format, Sahi was first so i have to give him the credit for the answer though.

Comment: my apologies, i must of misread the time stamp. I will change yours to the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

below Query can do the job

```
    Create table #tmp (col_A CHAR(1),col_b int,Username VARCHAR(10))

    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('1',5000,'John')
    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2',400,'John')
    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('1',499,'John')
    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2',3000,'John')

    SELECT * FROM #tmp

    select SUM(case when col_A='1' then col_b End) as Sum1_results,
         SUM(case when col_A='2' then col_b End) as Sum2_Results,Username 
    from #tmp

    group by col_A,UserName

    DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Results merged into one line for each username.

Create table #tmp (col_A CHAR(1),col_b int,Username VARCHAR(10))

```
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('1',5000,'John')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2',400,'John')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('1',499,'John')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('2',3000,'John')

SELECT * FROM #tmp

select SUM(case when col_A='1' then col_b End) as Sum1_results,
     SUM(case when col_A='2' then col_b End) as Sum2_Results,Username 
from #tmp

group by UserName

DROP TABLE #tmp
```